# How to download and then upload image with AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, image-uploading, image-upload

I have an Angularjs 1.5.0 web application which should communicate with a REST-based web service that I had developed (using dropwizard & jersey) and tested that it works perfectly.

The REST web service method is like this:

```
@POST
@Path("/saveImage")
public Response saveImage(
    @FormDataParam("imagefile") InputStream uploadedInputStream,
    @FormDataParam("imagefile") FormDataContentDisposition fileDetail) {

    // save image on server's file system and return OK
}
```

Scanned images are available to me by the scanner's local web server through a link like this: http://localhost:9980/thumb/random-generated-guid.jpg

In my angularjs code, I want to send the image which is available with the link above to my REST service.

**Does anybody know how to do this?**

I tried first saving the image as a blob and then send it to the web service. I could save the image using javascript's XMLHttpRequest but sending always fails.
Code for saving the image as **Blob**:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', imageAddress, true);
xhr.responseType = 'blob';
var imageData = null;

xhr.onload = function(e) {
    if (this.readyState === 4 && this.status === 200) {
        // get binary data as a response
        imageData = this.response;
        var gatewayResponse = sendToGateway(imageData);
    }
};
```

Code for sending the blob data:

```
var sendToGateway = function(imageDataBlob) {
        var formdata = new FormData();
        formdata.append('imagefile', imageDataBlob)
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost/eval/saveImage',
            method: 'POST',
            contentType: 'multipart/form-data; charset=UTF-8',
            data: formdata,
            dataType: 'json',
        })
        .done(function(response) {
            $log.info("**************** response = " + response);
            alert("response:\n" + response);
        })
        .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            $log.error("!!!! FAIL !!!!!!!!!");
            alert("FAIL !!!!!!!");
        })
        .always(function(){
            $rootScope.scannerInactive = false;
            doStartPreviewUpdate();
        });
    };
```

Actually, the problem is when the *sendToGateway(imageData);* is called, I get the error:

> TypeError: 'append' called on an object that does not implement
>   interface FormData.
>
> value = jQuery.isFunction( value ) ? value() : ( value == null ? "" :
>   value );

Comment: If the image is available through a URL which you mentioned why not just handle the uploading part on the server itself. Why bring angular in play. You can just pass the parameters as to what URL will give image and any other params you need. And in your saveImage function uploadong can be done using image upload API. Does that make sense?

Comment: @CoderJohn: actually, the REST web service is going to run on another server, that's why I can't do the uploading on the server side.

Answer (score 0):

oops, I found the problem. I should have added the following directives to the $.ajax() call.

```
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```